# Shell script for cron to send an email if the command produces any output

Tags: shell, cron, command

I'm trying to set up cron to run the following command inside a script:

```
find /path/to/folder -ctime -1 -type f
```

and send a mail if there were any created files in a specific folder for the past day. So far I have come up with this:

```
#!/bin/bash

check=$(find /path/to/folder -ctime -1 -type f)
alert=mail@mail.com

if [ "$check" -eq 0 ]
then
    mail -s "files created" "$alert"
fi
```

Problem is that I cannot execute the script even though [shell cheker](https://www.shellcheck.net/) says there are no errors. It gives me **syntax error: unexpected end of file**.

I have searched the web long enough to realise that other solutions like **MAILTO** and **MAILFROM** or scripts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14164383/check-a-files-modified-date-and-email-if-it-has-changed) won't work. I have also looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12137431/test-if-a-command-outputs-an-empty-string) thread but nothing seems to work and if I may add that this is for CentOS 6 in case it makes any difference.

Any help will be most appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6366607/2079249 - tried this?

Comment: it works now, thanks. I was also able to fix my code.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still interested in answer, here it is.

```
#!/bin/bash

check=$(find /path/to/folder -ctime -1 -type f)
alert=mail@mail.com

if [[ "$check" ]]
then
    echo "$check" | mail -s "files created" "$alert"
fi
```

Also make sure to convert CRLF line breaks to Unix style, if it doesn't work and you keep getting unexplained syntax error.

```
dos2unix /path/to/script
```

Or follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366530/bash-syntax-error-unexpected-end-of-file/6366607#6366607) link.